# How to make all controls visible in following panel example

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am new in winforms and i have problem that i can't solve by myself.

[image]

I want dynamically to add buttons to "bottom right panel" from the pic. Problem is that if I need to add large number of buttons then the buttons from the bottom of mentioned panel are covered with control (panel) that follows panel from the pic. This case shows when i first add "bottom right panel" to "right panel" and then "top right panel".

If i reverse that, and first add "bottom right panel" to "right panel" and then "top right panel" to "right panel" then the "top right panel" covers two button from the top of the bottom right panel but with scroll bar of "bottom right panel" reachs all other buttons (including the buttons from the bottom of bottom right panel).

My question is how to show all of the buttons from "bottom right panel"?

Thank you in advance and i hope you understand my English.

UPDATE:
Thank you guys for help but i didn't solve my problem although i tried all of yours tips. Now i give you more detail description what i want to achieve.

1. With splitContainers i achieve what i want but only if i split "root" panel. Here is that form and you can see that i get scroll in the spliter2.panel2 and i can reach all of the buttons (that is just what i need):

[image]

But my form where i need to add this panel looks like this:

[image]

Form adds "root" panel, "root" panel ads 3 panels (two black panels are docked top and bottom) and third one panel is panel we speak about and it is docked to fill.

Now, where I try to reduce size of form i get this:

[image]

Now i don't get scroll in spliter2.panel2 and some of my buttons disappear. I need scroll in spliter2.panel2 and i need that scroll to reach all the buttons.

Is it possible and how? Thank you all again...

UPDATE 2:
I need to add same behavior to one more form. The main diff (you can see on the picture bellow) is one more horizontal splitter on docked panel (root panel adds top, dock and bottom panels >> dock panel adds horizontal splitter >> dockPanelSplitter.Panel1 adds panel we speak about):

[image]

Again i don't have scroll although i set AutoScroll property of splitter3.Panel2 = true.

[image]

Comment: If you don't like the way "top right" and "bottom right" panels behave when **docked**, then you need to use something else.  In your "right panel", add a **TableLayoutPanel** and set it up with once column and two rows.  You'd add the "top right" and bottom right" panels to the rows in the TableLayoutPanel.  Now you can control the sizing relationship of the two rows in the TableLayoutPanel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 `SplitContainers`, one vertical, one horizontal, the second inside `Panel2` of the first and add your buttons dynamically (or through VS Designer) like this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Text = "Button1";
        button.Location = new Point(0, 10);
        splitContainer2.Panel2.Controls.Add(button);

        button = new Button();
        button.Text = "Button2";
        button.Location = new Point(0, 50);
        splitContainer2.Panel2.Controls.Add(button);
    }
```

Result:

[image]

**EDIT:** In order to get the scroll bars in the new scenario with the other panels, do this:

```
    splitContainer2.Panel2.AutoScroll = true;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Also, try using ToolStripContainer with the buttons in the toolStrips (ToolStripMenuItem or ToolStripButton) instead of using plain Buttons - they work great in combination with SplitContainers!

Comment: Please, can you check my question update. Your suggestion works great but that does not solve my problem... Thank you in advance...

Comment: Do this: `splitContainer2.Panel2.AutoScroll = true;`

Comment: Sorry, i now need to add exactly the same behavior but scenario is little different. Please check update. And can you give me link of some tutorials, resources about windows form designer? Just in order to avoid my questions in future :) Thank you for everything...

Comment: As the number of split containers and panels grow, it is easy to get lost among them, place controls on the wrong one, enable auto scroll on the wrong panel, etc. So, make sure you're clear about it. One more thing: even if you set auto scroll to true on the correct panel, the scroll bars will show up only when necessary. As for the tutorial I don't have a favorite one. If you google it, I am sure there's tons of them.